# string date and local time zone to specific strftime pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

Today I've encountered with a task that seems a bit tricky for me.
first, I need to convert date string `'2009-06-15T13:45:00Z'` to `datetime` obj, not a big deal:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime('2009-06-15T13:45:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

then, get local time zone:

```
from tzlocal import get_localzone
local = get_localzone()
```

and finally add/plus timezone hours to `datetime` object (what I don't know how to do better), so the time should be increased on hours(according to `tz` in mine `2`) and equal to:

```
value = datetetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
value -> '2009-06-15T15:45:00Z'
```

not like this: `'2009-06-15T13:45:00+02:00'`. coz with adding `.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` `2` hours disappear

```
datetime.strptime('2009-06-15T13:45:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').astimezone(tz=get_localzone()).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

I tried to add time via `timedelta`.

```
(
    datetime.strptime('2009-06-15T13:45:00Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ') + timedelta(hours=2)
).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

And it looked good, except the thing that I need is a dynamic time value. For instance according to the local time of machine where code is run.
I even found a solution, but it is a bit complicated. Might have missed something, and it's really peace of cake.

Comment: `get_localzone` should get you the delta for the timezone where the machine is running.

Comment: Note that your first conversion is wrong.  You have added 2 minutes, not 2 hours.

Comment: @TimRoberts you're right, my mistake, changed

Comment: @TimRoberts I guess you're right but when I use get_localzone, it adds only +02:00(2009-06-15T13:45:00+02:00), but then value back to the previous one 2009-06-15T13:45:00Z (without hours adding)

Comment: If you have a `datetime` in UTC, you should be able to use `dt.replace(tzinfo=get_localzone())` and have it shift for you.

Comment: @TimRoberts I added, but it shows 2009-06-15 13:45:00+03:00

Comment: That means your computer is set to +3.  Is this Linux?  If you do `cat /etc/timezone`, what does it say?

Comment: @TimRoberts like this:  timedatectl | grep "Time zone:"
                Time zone: Europe/Kiev (EET, +0200)
when use: cat /etc/timezone
cat: /etc/timezone: No such file or directory

Comment: Of COURSE it will show +3 hours.  2009-06-15 is in your summer time, when you ARE GMT+3.  And if you are in Ukraine, our best wishes to you.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```py
from dateutil import parser
time_str = '2009-06-15T13:45:00Z'
t = parser.parse(time_str)
# set to local timezone
local = t.astimezone(tz=None)
```

Comment: it looks great, honestly. but it pluses on 3 hours, but my local tz +2

Comment: tz=None _should_ set to the local machines timezone.  You can set tz to whatever you desire, e.g. using `from dateime import timedelta, timezone; t.astimezone(tz=timezone(timedelta(hours=-2))`